# Beautiful Soup 4 Custom Attribute Order Output

Tags: python-3.x, xml, dom, beautifulsoup, attributes

I want to create a custom output formatter in BS4 that will rearrange the order of attributes of tags in an XML in a specific way this is not alphabetical order.

For instance, I want to output the following tag:

```
<word form="συ" head="2610" id="2357" lemma="συ" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP"/>
```

as:

```
<word id="2357" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" form="συ" lemma="συ" relation="ExD_AP"/>
```

BS4's documentation offers a clue as to where to begin. They give the following example:

```
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            if k == 'm':
                continue
            yield k, v
print(attr_soup.p.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()))
```

This will make a custom HTML output formatter that will leave attributes in the order they were input and also ignore certain tags, but I don't know how to alter this so that it will output in whatever order I would like. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html ='''
<word form="συ" head="2610" id="2357" lemma="συ" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP"/>
'''
def toString(ele):
  order = ['id','head','postag','from','lemma','relation']
  result = '<'+ele.tag
  for p in order:
    result+=' {}="{}"'.format(p,ele[p])
  return result+'/>'
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
ele = doc.word
print (toString(ele))
```

Result:

```
<word id="2357" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" from="None" lemma="συ" relation="ExD_AP"/>
```

Comment: I might have to grab simplified-scrapy just for this purpose. Any idea if it handles XML ok? I know with BS4 if you don't specifically tell it you're working with XML, it alters your document to conform to HTML standards and that's not good for what I'm working with.

Comment: It basically doesn't change your document, except for some line breaks. He's lighter than bs4, no other dependencies, and faster. Here's an example: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, I have an answer to my own question, but it's going to take more work to actually implement it in a way I'd like. Here's how to do it.

Make a sub-class of the XMLFormatter (or HTMLFormatter if you're working with HTML), name it what you want. I chose "SortAttributes." Write the function "attributes" so that it will return a list of tuples: [(attribute1, value1), (attribute2, value2), etc.] in the order you want. Mine may look verbose, but I do it this way because I work with very inconsistent XML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import XMLFormatter


class SortAttributes(XMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        """Reorder a tag's attributes however you want."""
        attrib_order = ['id', 'head', 'postag', 'relation', 'form', 'lemma']
        new_order = []
        for element in attrib_order:
            if element in tag.attrs:
                new_order.append((element, tag[element]))
        for pair in tag.attrs.items():
            if pair not in new_order:
                new_order.append(pair)
        return new_order


xml_string = '''
<word form="συ" head="2610" id="2357" lemma="συ" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP"/>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, 'xml')
print(soup.encode(formatter=SortAttributes()))
```

This will output what I want:

```
<word id="2357" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP" form="συ" lemma="συ"/>
```

Conveniently, I can do this for an entire document with the same encode method. But if I write that to a file as a string, then all the tags are just strung together end to end. A sample would be like such:

```
<sentence id="783"><word id="2357" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP" form="συ" lemma="συ"/><word id="2358" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP" form="συ" lemma="συ"/><word id="2359" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP" form="συ" lemma="συ"/></sentence>
```

Instead of something I'd prefer:

```
<sentence id="783">
  <word id="2357" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP" form="συ" lemma="συ"/>
  <word id="2358" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP" form="συ" lemma="συ"/>
  <word id="2359" head="2610" postag="p-s----n-" relation="ExD_AP" form="συ" lemma="συ"/>
</sentence>
```

To fix that, I can't just .prettify it because prettify rearranges the attributes back to alphabetical order. I'll have to go into more details with the XMLFormatter subclass instead. I hope someone finds this helpful in the future!

Comment: If you use SimplifiedDoc's solution, you can add line breaks:) such as return result + '/>\n'

Comment: You can also use regex unification to handle line breaks after the rearrangement. re.sub(re.compile('/><'), '/>\n<, html)

Comment: Just adding as a reference for anyone who is looking for this as well - you can simply pass this XMLFormatter subclass to the prettify()-method and it works a charm.